Is there a difference between nonconvex and concave for geometric solids?
For 2D shapes, nonconvex and concave are clearly the same thing since failing the convex set test:

(where part of $\overline{\text{xy}}$ is not contained in the shape) means the shape is concave since that part "caves in" or is indented.  However, for certain geometric solids, it's not as clear to me.  For example, while a torus

is nonconvex since the diameter fails the convex set test, is it concave?  There's no indentation on the surface, unless the negative curvature of the interior counts as indentation.  Or is my definition of concave wrong?

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Concave.html
